# How to update an input's value after calling $setViewValue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a form input with a `ng-model` as well as my custom directive which reads cookie data and should set the input value:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" ng-model="name" my-cookie-directive>
</form>
```

My directive:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives').directive('myCookieDirective', ['CookieService', function(CookieService) {

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            var cookieVal = CookieService.getCookie(attrs.ngModel);

            if(cookieVal != '') {
                ctrl.$setViewValue(cookieVal);
                elem.val(cookieVal); //not very cool hum?
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

When logging `ctrl.$modelValue` I can see that the right cookie data was set to my controller variable `name` but the input stays blank. I know that `$setViewValue` does not trigger a `$digest` and therefore tried `ctrl.$render()` but nothing happens.

I ended up using *jQuery* to set the `input`'s value which is not satisfying at all.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in not wanting to use jQuery to set the input's value. Why would you be using Angular if you are going to do that then?

You can see a new Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PXcvZ6IiPVufBY2dTWGj?p=preview), using a different approach to the ones being mentioned. My suggestion: use NgModelController when you want to handle validations and format the model value.

For your current situation, you can use an isolated scope in the directive, and pass to it the scope property you want to update with the cookie value. Then in the directive, you can simply do:

```
scope.cookieField = cookieVal;
```

And Angular will handle the data binding and update the view value to match the model value. Plus, this is completely reusable.

Comment: If the OP goes this route, they could simplify things a bit by using their directive name attribute itself to set the 'name' field: http://plnkr.co/edit/eecMnc1GcoFVWPrflYm5?p=preview

Comment: @marck Indeed. I'm not a big fan of using the directive name to set properties in the scope, so I avoid this practice. But it's just a personal preference, if perfectly valid of course. Some people even say that it looks like you have two directives, so it might be better the way you suggested it.

Comment: Well if you don't like that approach, seeing this one (using ngModel to set the scope variable) might make it hard for you to sleep tonight: http://plnkr.co/edit/eecMnc1GcoFVWPrflYm5?p=preview :) ... but it does match the original HTML

Comment: Using an isolated scope should work in this case. Thank you for your time. Though, I resolved this issue by implementing a service to write to the browsers `localStorage` since cookies are so 90s ;) If anyone is interested in my solution feel free to ask how

Answer (score 2):

Use `$render` and wrap everything in a function passed to `$evalAsync`:

```
if(cookieVal !== '') {
    scope.$evalAsync(function(){
      ctrl.$setViewValue(cookieVal);
      ctrl.$render();
    });
}
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/hTkGOii1HcM5VUpozxwN?p=preview)